# How to manually specify variables for child pipeline in bridge job?

Tags: gitlab, cicd

Right now i have this gitlab-ci.yml.

```
stages:
  - Build
  - Deploy

...

Deploy:
  stage: Deploy
  when: manual
  trigger: services/service1
  variables:
    BUILD_NAME: "${BUILD_NAME}"
```

Unfortunately, screen "Specifying variables" does not open. How to specify variables for downstream pipeline which will be triggered by Deploy job in this format - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/index.html#specifying-variables-when-running-manual-jobs.